# VectorLayer don't toggle visibity, always turned on

Tags: openlayers

I have a VectorLayer with some points generated by the user, configured this way:

```js
var sourcePoint = new VectorSource();
var vectorPoint = new VectorLayer({
    source: sourcePoint,
    style: new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        }),
        image: new CircleStyle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new Fill({
                color: '#32ff32'
            }) 
        })
    }),
    zIndex: 99,
    name: "vectorPoint",
    visible: false
});
```

When the map page opens it loads the user data and populate in sourcePoint. The problem is that this vectorLayer must start with visibity setted to false, but even with the `visible: false` it starts turned on.

I also tried to toggle this layer visibility with the [`setVisible()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer-Layer.html#setVisible) function, which is also not working with this layer. What is strange is that other VectorLayers are working fine as suppose to, starting with visibility set to off and toggling.

Is there any reason why this might be happening? I can't find anyone with a similar problem.

---

**Update 17/02/2020**

How I`m adding the layer to the map:

```js
this.map = new Map({
    layers: [tileBackground, vectorPoint],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: view
});
```

The basic toggle layers function I'm using

```js
randomFunction(status, layerName) { // Firing as randomFunction(true, 'vectorPoint')
    this.map.getLayers().forEach((layer) => {
        if (layer.get('name') == layerName && layer.get('name') != undefined) {
            if (status == true) {
                layer.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                layer.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I can see that the layer is founded after `if (layer.get('name') == layerName...`

---

Comment: Can you add the code when you add the layers to the map?, and any part that you change visibility?.

Comment: Of course, check the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I manage to find the problem. The error in this case is that I had other vector layer for points created with the GPS of the device. When the points are loaded, they populated both of the layers, so when I tried to turn the main point layers off, the other was still active, misleading me to believe that the error was with the method I was using. I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Good you figure it out, sorry I could not check until now.